# Write logary target to EventStore

Tags: c#, logging, f#, eventstoredb, logary

I need to write Logary target to store logs to the EventStore from .NET application.

I have followed the following instructions: https://freesoft.dev/program/20382492#writing-a-new-target.

Now I have a new file with the same content as Noop.fs that I want to change so that I would be able to send my logs to the EventStore. The part that I need to edit is this one:

```
...     
 | Log (message, ack) ->

//ADD HERE
...
```

I am not sure what I need to add. Somehow parse the message according to its importance? Add timestamp to the message? Send it to the EventStore using the address of the EventStore? Perhaps an example of how it should look like, at least in pseudocode?